# angular-ui/ui-select: how to set initial selected object correctly

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

This is my ui select in the view:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedLabel.selected" ng-disabled="fetchingLabels || working">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{$select.selected.code}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="label in labels| filterBy: ['name', 'code']: $select.search"> 
        <div ng-bind-html="label.code | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small ng-bind-html="label.name | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And this is the relevant code in my controller:

```
$scope.labels = [];
$scope.selectedLabel = {};
$scope.selectedLabel.selected = $scope.passedLabel; // This is an object passed 
                                                    // from the previous controller.
                                                    // The scope comes with it.


$scope.fetchLabels(); // This fetches the labels from the server
                      // and puts them in $scope.labels
```

The labels brought from the server are **theoretically** like these:

```
[{'labelId': 20, 'code': 'L20', 'name': 'some label'},
 {'labelId': 21, 'code': 'L21', 'name': 'other label'}, ...]
```

And the passed from-outside label, 'passedLabel', is **theoretically** like ONE of those in `$scope.labels` too, eg:

```
  passedLabel = {'labelId': 21, 'code': 'L21', 'name': 'other label'}
```

...I say **theoretically** because, empirically, I'm seeing that they are different because of the things that angular adds to them (eg. `$$hashKey`, or `__proto__`).

So, because of that *difference*, the `$scope.selectedLabel.selected = $scope.passedLabel` isn't matching the corresponding item in the ui-select (they are not the same object), and thus, the result of that is this behavior:

[image: ui-select behavior with initial selection]

How can I set the initial selection **correctly**? is there a way I can use id's instead of object comparisson? I want to avoid having a `for` like this:

```
  for (i=0; i<$scope.labels; i++) {
      if ($scope.labels[i].labelId == $scope.passedLabel.labelId) {
           $scope.selectedLabel.selected = $scope.labels[i]
      }
  }
```

which I'm pretty sure it would work as expected, but I would have to call that `for` after the ajax has returned... and I have other ui-selects too

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem other then the for loop you suggested? I'm having the same problem and I really don't like the search & replace thing for the initial value. A live demo of the issue can be found [at plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bK6JNpIRL4jTQWt3AXey?p=preview). When using a regular drop down we can achieve this via a track by expression, angular material can do it via [`ng-model="foo" ng-model-options="{ trackBy: '$value.id' }"`](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/select/select.js). I really want to do something similar with ui-select ...

Comment: no, I didn't find a solution, sorry... I ended up repeating the selected element, that is: The initial selected item is at the top (well, selected) and if you scroll down you can find it again somewhere in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to achieve the state that you have mentioned, then simply pass the correct reference to your model.

So after the success of the fetchlabel call you set the values in labels. Now in the success of this function you need to call the function that fetches `presentLabel`.

As soon as you get the data of present label you can get the index of that object in the labels scope.

```
var idx;
_.find($scope.labels, function(label, labelIdx){ 
  if(label.labelId == parentLabel.labelId){ idx = labelIdx; return true;}; 
});

$scope.selectedLabel = {};
$scope.selectedLabel.selected = $scope.labels[idx];
```

This will solve your purpose.

Comment: the `_.find()` is somehow similar to the `for` I had at the end of my post?

Comment: Yes you shall get same result. However underscore is much recommended utility as it gives readability